# Qt wait for POST to complete

Tags: c++, qt, http, post, httprequest

How would I write a function to wait for POST to complete? I am logging into a website that has multiple redirects and using connect() with `QNetworkReply()` leads to infinite GET requests.

I'm using a wait timer right now:

```
test->sendPostRequest(url, loginData);

    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer::singleShot(8000, &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();


   test->sendGetRequest(request);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear pls explain it a bit more . do u want to uplaod file and why not you execute post in{ QEventLoop loop; post loop.exec(); } these statements

Comment: why not use a second function and use the signal slot properly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a local event loop using `QEventLoop` and connecting the signal finished of your `QNetworkAccessManager` to the quit slot of `QEventLoop`. This way when the post is finished, the local event loop quits and the rest gets executed :

```
QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

networkManager->post(QNetworkRequest(serviceUrl), postData);


QEventLoop loop;
loop.connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(quit())); 
loop.exec();

//...
```

I should not that it's the standard pattern for "blocking wait without blocking the UI".